# quiz application: verifying correct answers

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm constructing a quiz application and am having trouble verifying whether or not user answers are correct. The quiz contains 10 questions, and uses radio buttons to get answers from the user. For some questions, none of the answers register as correct, and for some of the other questions, all of the answers register as correct.

Each question has its own 'questionClass,' outlined like so:

```
function questionClass (q, a1, a2, a3, a4, n, c) {
this.question = q;
this.answer1 = a1;
this.answer2 = a2;
this.answer3 = a3;
this.answer4 = a4;
this.number = n;
this.correct = c;
```

Each of the question classes are created with the following formula:

```
var questionOne = new questionClass("quotation to be analyzed", 'answer1','answer2','answer3','answer4', number, 'correct');
questions.push(questionOne);
```

The function for verifying whether or not the user got the correct answer is here:

```
    this.checkAnswer=checkAnswer;
    function checkAnswer() {

    if ($('input:radio[name=" ' + this.number + ' "]:checked').val() == this.correct) {
        score++;
    }
    else if ($('input:radio[name=" ' + this.number + ' "]:checked').val() == this.correct) {
        score++;
    }
    else if ($('input[id=" ' + this.answer3 + ' "]:checked') && (this.answer3 == this.correct)) {
        score++;
    }
    else if ($('input[id=" ' + this.answer4 + ' "]:checked') && (this.answer4 == this.correct)) {
        score++;
    }
    else {
        console.log("you got the wrong answer");
    }

}
```

The function for moving between questions is as follows:

```
$("#continue").click(function(){
    counter++;

    if (counter == 1) {
        questions[x].display();
    }
    else if ((counter >= 1) && (counter <= 10)) {
        if (questions[x].isSelected()) {
            $('.warning').html("");
            questions[x].checkAnswer();
            $('.score').html("<p>Your score is " + score + " out of 10</p>");
            x++;
                if (x < 10){
                    questions[x].display();
                }
        }
    }
    else if ((counter >= 11) && (!questions[x].isSelected())) {
        return;
    }
    else {
        $('.warning').html("");
        questions[x].checkAnswer();
        $('.score').empty();
        $('#container').html('<h1>You scored ' + score + ' out of 10.</h1></br>');
        $('#container').append('<input type="button" id="tryAgain" value="Try Again!">');

    }
});
```

The application can be viewed at this link:

http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/91499081/QuizApp/quizApp.html

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/MCjna/

Comment: a jsfiddle would be very helpful

Comment: take code you have in link and put it in jsfiddle.net where others can play with it

Comment: here is a jsfiddle with all of my code, though the "continue" button isn't working in it, even though it works on the application page that i linked above.  http://jsfiddle.net/thektulu/TrFmJ/